# Numbers not adding with +=

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I don't know why this is not adding up and printing the same 5 times

```
import time
rn1to5 = random.randint(1, 5)

def trees(treePriority, treeFarmLevel, treeCount):
    treeCount += treePriority * treeFarmLevel + 1
    print(treeCount)

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(0)
    trees(rn1to5, 1, 0)
import random
import time
rn1to5 = random.randint(1, 5)

def trees(treePriority, treeFarmLevel, treeCount):
    treeCount += treePriority * treeFarmLevel + 1
    print(treeCount)

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(0)
    trees(rn1to5, 1, 0)
```

Comment: You pass the same values to ``trees``, thus you get the same results.

Comment: The original variable is never updated -- only the function argument is.

Comment: @Graverman: it seems that your code is pasted twice. Please [edit] the question and remove the duplicate code

Comment: More importantly, please [edit] to provide a single, well-defined question with a [mre].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is with the generation of the random number. You are expecting a different number just by running the loop again and again but you are generating the random number only once at the top.

So your code just gets the random number b/w 1 and 5 and does the operation with that.

What you want is you want to get different result every time which is possible only if you are getting the random number everytime the loop runs.

Here is the code;

```
import random
import time


def trees(treePriority, treeFarmLevel, treeCount):
    treeCount += treePriority * treeFarmLevel + 1
    print(treeCount)

for i in range(5):
    rn1to5 = random.randint(1, 5)
    time.sleep(0)
    trees(rn1to5, 1, 0)
```

**EDIT:** sorry got your question wrong. But here is the solution;

```
import random
import time
rn1to5 = random.randint(1, 5)

def trees(treePriority, treeFarmLevel, treeCount):    
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0)
        treeCount += treePriority * treeFarmLevel + 1
    print(treeCount)

trees(rn1to5, 1, 0)
```

Leaving the rest part of my answer there just for info.

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry for misunderstanding. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

solution there:

```
import time
import random
rn1to5 = random.randint(1, 5)

def trees(treePriority, treeFarmLevel, treeCount):
    treeCount += treePriority * treeFarmLevel + 1
    print(treeCount)
    return treeCount
treeCount = 0
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(0)
    treeCount = trees(rn1to5, 1, treeCount)
```

output:

```
python3 prueba.py 
3
6
9
12
15
```

just need to return value from function to fix it

Operator += its working fine:

```
a = 3
print(a)
b = 1
a += b
print(a)
```

output:

```
python3 prueba.py 
3
4
```